# Put P4 move operation in a non default changelist

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to do a `p4 move` to retain the perforce history. P4 moves created a delete/add operation in my default changelist. The documentation assures me that p4 move will retain history via an 'integration record'.

Now I want to submit the `p4 move` (delete/add) operation part of a changelist. How do I make sure that Perforce will do the move properly rather then delete/add as currently indicated by my changelist and lose the history? Can I see if the 'activation record' will created when the changelist is submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `p4 opened` to see the status of the opened files in your changelist. The following sequence of commands illustrates what happens during a `p4 move`.

```
$ p4 open icons.zip
$ p4 opened 
//full/depot/path/to/icons.zip#1 - edit default change (ubinary)
$ p4 move icons.zip foo.zip
//full/depot/path/to/foo.zip#1 - moved from //full/depot/path/to/icons.zip#1
$ p4 opened
//full/depot/path/to/foo.zip#1 - move/add default change (ubinary)
//full/depot/path/to/icons.zip#1 - move/delete default change (ubinary)
$ p4 changelist 
Change 350425 created with 2 open file(s).
$ p4 opened
//full/depot/path/to/foo.zip#1 - move/add change 350425 (ubinary)
//full/depot/path/to/icons.zip#1 - move/delete change 350425 (ubinary)
```

As you can see, the creation of a new pending changelist didn't change the status of the opened files at all, it pertains the `move/add + move/delete` action. If this is not what you were looking for, please edit your question.

Note: the above was tested with P4D/2009.2 (Server) and p4/2010.1 (Client).

Comment: Haha, I had no p4 at hand and assumed the OP had tried p4 opened and that is was not informative. +1

Comment: I was mislead to believe that the eclipse p4 plugin's changelist pane was similar to p4 opened. p4 opened give me exactly the info I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to query for a pending move operation.

If I don't know what operation is pending but I know that it should be a move and it is vital for me that the submit record be a move, then I would revert the files in question and again call `p4 move` on them.

Update: I see in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886604/put-p4-move-operation-in-a-non-default-changelist/3888780#3888780) that `p4 opened` reports pending moves.

Answer (score 0):

P4 creates 2 changes for move:

move/add and move/delete

You can commit those and both will be in the changelist.